# How can I calculate how many times process a function in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, counter, calculated-field

```
<div id="element1" onclick="func();">1</div>
<div id="element2" onclick="func();">2</div>
<div id="element3" onclick="func();">3</div>
<div id="element4" onclick="func();">4</div>
<div id="element5" onclick="func();">5</div>
<div id="element6" onclick="func();">6</div>
<div id="element7" onclick="func();">7</div>
<div id="element8" onclick="func();">8</div>
```

When user click any div, func() function will work and a counter calculate how many times process func() function. For example 2 times (we determine the number) process func() function than when user click any div again function will not work. How can I do this with jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a global variable to track the number of times the function is called.

```
var counter = 0;

function func() {

    counter++;
    if (counter > 2) return;

    // do other fn stuff
}
```

On a slightly related note, there is a better way of binding multiple click handlers when using jQuery:

```
$('div[id^="element"]').click( func );
```

Of course, it doesn't really matter since `return` will halt execution, but if you didn't want `func` to be called at all (i.e. if you wanted to remove the click event altogether), you could then simply do (if you make the change above):

```
$('div[id^="element"]').unbind('click');
```

This would be in place of the `return` statement in the first section of code.

Comment: Thank you very much.it's very useful for me.Problem solve thank you thank you